# ReferenceError: auto is not defined using google maps using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have this GoogleMaps library in CodeIgniter and I've test it to see if the map will render in my views page. What happen is when I see in my views page I got this line of error.

```
ReferenceError: auto is not defined
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), auto);
```

In my view I use this line of code

```
<?php echo $map['javascript']; ?>
```

to render the code in map for javascript and this line of code too

```
<?php echo $map['mapdiv']; ?>
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out about this line of error?

```
ReferenceError: auto is not defined


map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), auto);
```

It says referenceError auto is not defined.
Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

When `auto` is `undefined` , it hasn't been defined somewhere, that's how it is(impossible to say more without seeing the library).

But you better shouldn't use this library, as it seems it uses the APIV2 which has been deprecated for years and has been turned off.

However, to fix the error use this line:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But ummm how do i able to set on that since my javascript im using is this line of code
<?php echo $map['javascript']; ?>
and the javascript code is automatically rendered..

Comment: As I said, I would not use this library